# Designing a membership database with link metrics

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

So just to summarize what this membership is:

It has users who will use tools to find web page URLs and the system will run metrics (Google Pagerank, SEOMoz PA & DA, Alexa rank, etc) on it. Users will be able to save these web pages, their metrics and export them.

Say I have these MySQL tables:

```
Users_table
----------
user_id PK
login_name
other_user_stuff...

Users_Links_table
----------------
user_id FK
link_id FK

Links_table
-----------
link_id PK
page_url
```

By the way, if you think this design is bad, do let me know.

So my question is, how should I be storing the metrics for the links? Should I expand the Links_table? Method A.

```
Links_table
-----------
link_id PK
page_url
metric1
metric2
more metrics down the road ...
```

Or should I put the metrics in a separate table? Method B.

```
Link_Metrics_table
------------------
metric_id PK
link_id FK
metric_type (string)
metric_value (string)
```

Or should it be like this? Method C.

```
Link_Metrics_table
------------------
metric_id PK
metric_type_id FK
link_id FK
metric_value

Link_Metrics_Types_table
------------------------
metric_type_id PK
metric_type_name
```

Or Method D?

```
Link_Metrics_table
------------------
metric_id PK
link_id FK
metric1
metric2
metric3
metric (n+1)
```

If anyone could shed light on how to design this would be greatly appreciated, especially to account for metric types that may be added further down the road. Thanks.

**Edit:**

Now that I've taken care of this I ran into a problem of not knowing how to perform a particular query.

Given the database structure I chose (Method C), how do I write the query in order to get a result set like this:

```
link_id     link_url     metric_1       metric_2       metric_3       metric_n+1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           google.com   metric_1_val   metric_2_val   metric_3_val   metric_n+1_val
```

Where any given metric may or may not exist.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Looks like I figured it out, I used this:

```
SELECT 
  l.link_id, 
  l.page_url,
  IF(t.metric_type_id=1, m.metric_value, 'N/A') AS metric_1, 
  IF(t.metric_type_id=4, m.metric_value, 'N/A') AS metric_2 
FROM 
  Links_table l,
  Link_Metrics_table m, 
  Link_Metrics_Types_table t 
WHERE
  l.link_id=m.link_id AND 
  m.metric_type_id=t.metric_type_id
```

If this is the wrong way to go about it please let me know.

Comment: not really a 'right' answer - many people like the key-value pair option here. (Method B) - upside, you can add new metrics at will.. downside - harder to query

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc can you explain why C would be better?

Comment: @rclai89: Sure.  Option C is normalized.  You can join the tables to query almost anything.  The problem with option B is that it's difficult to write SQL queries to retrieve the key / value pairs.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Oh wow, I forgot to put FK `link_id` on the Link_Metrics_table on Method C. I just edited it. Would that still be normalized?

Comment: Hey guys, I added new stuff to my question and was wondering if I can call upon your help once again? It's the stuff below the **Edit** section. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, looks like I figured it out, I just had to do a SELECT IF(expr1, expr2, expr3) AS metric_n+1.